# asp.net mvc create a c# class in an ascx file for design purposes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am developing a web application using asp.net mvc.

I have come across the need to ***Temporarily*** create a class in the ascx/aspx file.
This class will replace the Model during the development of the page.
It will also hold some test data for the user to have the chance to see some results.

Once we are happy with the layout on the screen, I will inherit the correct Model class through the Control tag.

Can you please advise if this is possible and how to do it?

This does not work:

```
<%
    class Modelo
    {
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
%>
```

**Edit:**
I have found that when I am sitting with the user and we are discussing the specifics of a control on the screen, in many cases when he/she sees the results and we discuss them he/she asks to change something. Moving between the controller, the model and the fake data repository consumes time. Even though the user is quit intelligent he/she can not follow what I am doing and feels less involved. If every thing was in one place I could explain to them what I am doing , they would at least feel that they know what is happening and we spend more time working and less time waiting for me to switch between screens. After he/she leaves I can sit down quietly and implement the agreed solution quietly. By keeping a class with fake data representing the model on the actual control all I will need to do is some housekeeping to meet the MVC way of doing things.

Hope it is more clear now.

Thanks in advance, Be happy - Julian

Comment: Perhaps if you were to more clearly explain what you're trying to do, and perhaps why you are trying to do it.  My first guess is that you're trying to do something the hard way that MVC already has a much easier way to handle.

Comment: @Mystere Man - Editing my question - hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative approach that would meet your needs could be as follows:

You base your view on a ViewModel as you would normally, however you copy the view model into a 'DisplayModel' local variable that you use for display purposes.  The values in this can be set locally during the development demo stage - if no values have been supplied by the controller.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyViewModel>" %>

<%
  MyViewModel displayModel = MyViewModel;

  if (displayModel == null) 
  {
     displayModel = new MyViewModel {
        Property1 = "Test Value 1",
        Property2 = 100.00,
        Property3 = true
     };
  }
%>

<%= displayModel.Property1 %>
<%= displayModel.Property2 %>
<%= displayModel.Property3 %>
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer as it seems the closest that we can get to my original request - Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly hardcode the values in the view? Another possibility is to use the real model class but use a dummy repository inside the controller which will fill the model with temporary data. Once the final repository is ready all you have to do is instruct your DI framework to pass the real repository to the controller.

IMHO creating temporary classes inside the views wouldn't bring much value nor you will gain time.

Comment: hello again - as always thanks for your excellent remarks, I have added an explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @Julian - In my opinion, Darin's response still stands. You won't gain anything from your desired approach.

Comment: @Julian, isn't hardcoding the values in your view an acceptable solution? This way you have them all in one place so that you don't need to switch between views and controllers.

Comment: @Dan At the moment I am hard coding values into fields. The problem with this approach is that when there are several parts to a page For example a master list that has a details section and within that section there is a table that one of the fields is a dropdown and for each row in the table the dropdown is different, it becomes very complex to manage the hard coded values. If I could create the class in the view I could at least reduce complexity. I know it sounds like a mess but the screens are very logical at the end. (In some cases I have introduced partials to reduce complexity)

Comment: @Dan I am also using dictionaries and lists to simplify the situation. I would prefer to enter the exact class, If this is not possible then I will continue with the hard coded approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't really achieve what you want, as the view processor is not exactly like a code behind.

Your best bet would be to create a temporary class in your controller, and then pass that to the view.  At least it takes some steps out of the way, and it shouldn't take too long to switch between only two windows.